# ASP:NET MVC custom AuthorizeAttribute filterContext.result not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am trying to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` for AJAX requests like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.Data = new { status = "unauthorized", redirect = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl };
            filterContext.Result = result;
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            return;
        }
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
```

However it the `JSONResult` is for some reason never written to the HTTP Response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way to fix this but it works for me: Instead of adding the `JSONResult` to the `filterContext` I wrote the JSON String directly to the HTTP response like this:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
string json =  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result.Data);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(json);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

if need initialize filterContext.Result, then AuthorizeCore must return true. For example:

```
private ActionResult _unAuthorizedResult;

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
        try
        {
            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;

            var allow = PrivateMethod_CheckAllow();

            if (!allow && NeedReturnActionResult())
            {
                _unAuthorizedResult = GetNotAllowActionResult();
                return true;
            }

            return allow;
        }
        catch (AuthorizeException)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
}

public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

    if (_unAuthorizedResult != null)
    {
        filterContext.Result = _unAuthorizedResult;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    }
}
```